# Structuring/Nesting of json data to populate a tree grid

Tags: json, extjs, extjs4.1

I have been struggling to populate a tree grid with json data.  I am reading the data from database and then loading it to the tree grid.

The json data that I get from database is in similar format as given below:

```
{   "data": [{            
    "bike": "Yamaha",
    "color": "Black",
    "cost": 870000
},{
    "bike": "Honda",
    "color": "Red",
    "cost": 675000
},{
    "bike": "Honda",
    "color": "Blue",
    "cost": 690000
},{
    "bike": "Suzuki",
    "color": "White",
    "cost": 800000"
},{
    "bike": "Harley",
    "color": "Yellow",
    "cost": 980000
},{
    "bike": "Harley",
    "color": "Black",
    "cost": 880000
}]}
```

In my tree panel, the first column is a tree column.
I have set the below properties for tree panel

```
                displayField: 'bike',
                rootVisible: false,
                useArrows: true,
```

I am able to load it to the tree grid but the thing is for each data is displayed in seperate node in the tree. I know this is because the json structure is not suitable for the tree.

I want to convert or nest the json data in a particular format as given below:

```
{"data": [{            
    "bike": "Yamaha",
    "data": [{
        "bike": "Yamaha",
        "color": "Black",
        "cost": 870000
    }]
},{
    "bike": "Honda",
    "data": [{
        "bike": "Honda",
        "color": "Red",
        "cost": 675000
    },
    {
        "bike": "Honda",
        "color": "Blue",
        "cost": 690000      
    }]
},{
    "bike": "Suzuki",
    "data": [{
        "bike": "Suzuki",
        "color": "White",
        "cost": 800000"
    }]
},{
    "bike": "Harley",
    "data": [{
        "bike": "Harley",
        "color": "Yellow",
        "cost": 980000
    }]
},{
    "bike": "Harley",
    "data": [{
        "bike": "Harley",
        "color": "Black",
        "cost": 880000
    }]
}]}
```

So that I can get the below output..

[image]

I am not sure how to convert the json data. I was not able to find suitable solution in the web. Please help

This is how my store looks like:

```
var MyStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
        autoLoad: true,
        autoSync: true,
        storeId: 'MyStore',
        model: 'model',
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            api: {
                read: 'http://localhost/Files/data.json'
            },
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                messageProperty: 'message',
                successProperty: 'success',
                root: 'data',
                totalProperty: 'total'
            }
        }
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this myself...
I had to modify my SQL query itself to get the Json data in the nested format for populating the tree grid:

// I get the value of the node param

```
$node = $_POST['node'];
if (empty($node)){
    $node = $_GET['node'];
}
```

// Based on the type of node I query data

```
if (strcmp(strtolower($node),"root")==0) {
    // If root node then query all bikes with remaining data as null for setting the parent nodes
    $query = "Select 'PARENT_' || b.id as ID, Null as color, Null as cost from Bikes b";    
} else {
    // Splitting the Id from string
    $node = explode("_", $node);
    $nodeType = $node[0];
    $bikeID = $node[1];

    if (strcmp(strtolower($nodeType),"parent")==0) {            
        // if node is a parent node, then load all child nodes based on bike ID
        $query = "select 'CHILD_' || b.id as ID, b.color as color, b.cost as cost from Bikes b where b.id = ".sprintf('%d',intval($bikeID));                    
    }
}
// execute the query
execute($query);
```

Answer (score 0):

What is your root config in the Tree Store look like? By default, the expected root property for nested data is "children", but can be changed (in your case) to "data"

Comment: I had a doubt on that, I dint know what exactly to put in the root config. Can you tell me what exactly should I set in the root config of my store in this case?

Comment: @existdissolvevar I have included my store in my question above

Answer (score 0):

The data format is correct, but you've got a syntax error in it:

```
{
    "bike": "Suzuki",
    "data": [{
        "bike": "Suzuki",
        "color": "White",
        "cost": 800000"
    }]
}
```

There's an unexpected `"` char after the cost. With that fixed, the data works with a tree configured like this:

```
Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    ,height: 300
    ,rootVisible: false

    ,columns: [{
        xtype: 'treecolumn'
        ,dataIndex: 'bike'
        ,text: 'Bikes'
    },{
        dataIndex: 'color'
        ,text: 'Color'
        ,flex: 2
    },{
        dataIndex: 'cost'
        ,text: 'Cost'
    }]    

    ,store: {
        autoLoad: true,
        autoSync: true,
        fields: ['bike', 'color', 'cost'],
        proxy: {
            type: 'memory'
            ,reader: {
                type: 'json'
                ,root: 'data'
            }
            ,data: data // that's your data object
        }
    }
});
```

Also, if your server isn't supporting filtering (e.g. flat json file), or if you want to avoid numerous request (which is probably why you're trying to load nested data in the first place), you'll have to add `leaf: true` to all nodes that are... well, leaves. Or the store will make server request for each non-leave nodes.